# Easy way to flatten XML file with LINQ

Tags: xml, linq

Is there an easy way with LINQ to flatten an XML file?

I can see a number of ways with XSLT but wondered what the best option with LINQ would be?

I cant put the xml structure up exactly as stackoverflow seems to filter chevron chars. But its something like this

nodeA

--nodeA1

--nodeA2

NodeB

I want to end up with

nodeA

nodeA1

nodeA2

NodeB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK; it depends on the output you want - with XElement you'd need to do a bit of work to remove all the descendent nodes etc. However, it is actually quite simple with XmlDocument:

```cs
string xml = @"<xml><nodeA><nodeA1/><nodeA2/></nodeA><NodeB/></xml>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlDocument clone = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = (XmlElement) clone.AppendChild(clone.CreateElement("xml"));
foreach(XmlElement el in doc.SelectNodes("//*")) {
    root.AppendChild(clone.ImportNode(el, false));
}
Console.WriteLine(clone.OuterXml);
```

Outputs:

```
<xml><xml /><nodeA /><nodeA1 /><nodeA2 /><NodeB /></xml>
```

---

[was]
Care to define "flatten" in this context? i.e. "before" and "after"?
XDocument has Descendants() and DescendantNodes() which might do the job...

Comment: Nope it does not give a flat list

Answer (score 1):

using an extension method this is really easy to do :

```
public static class XElementExtensions
{
    public static string Path(this XElement xElement)
    {
        return PathInternal(xElement);
    }

    private static string PathInternal(XElement xElement)
    {
        if (xElement.Parent != null)
            return string.Concat(PathInternal(xElement.Parent), ".", xElement.Name.LocalName);

        return xElement.Name.LocalName;
    }
}
```

then :

```
private static void Main()
{
    string sb =@"<xml>
                <nodeA>
                    <nodeA1>
                        <inner1/><inner2/>
                    </nodeA1>
                    <nodeA2/>
                </nodeA>
                <NodeB/>
                </xml>";

    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(sb);

    var result = xDoc.Root.Descendants()
        .Select(r => new {Path = r.Path()});

    foreach (var p in result)
        Console.WriteLine(p.Path);
}
```

results in :

```
xml.nodeA
xml.nodeA.nodeA1
xml.nodeA.nodeA1.inner1
xml.nodeA.nodeA1.inner2
xml.nodeA.nodeA2
xml.NodeB
```

Answer (score 0):

The last part of what Marc said is what I think you're looking for. Here is an example that you can drop into [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and see the results of the "flatten."

```
string xml = @"<xml><nodeA><nodeA1><inner1/><inner2/></nodeA1><nodeA2/></nodeA><NodeB/></xml>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

doc.Dump();
doc.Root.Descendants().Dump();
doc.Descendants().Dump();
doc.Root.Descendants().Count().Dump();
doc.Descendants().Count().Dump();
```

Comment: None of these actually flatten the XML.