# Flattening an xml file using ref attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'd like to flatten an xml data file (note that this is not a schema, .xsd, file) programatically using C# (so an external xml editor won't work, unless it has an API).  For an example tree structure:

```
<root>
    <A>
        <B att="val">
            <C>
                someData
            </C>
        </B>
    </A>
    <A>
        <B>
             someOtherData
        </B>
        <B>
            moreData
        </B>
    </A>
</root>
```

I'd like to flatten it to:

```
<root>
    <A>
        <B ref="b1" />
    </A>
    <A>
        <B ref="b2" />
        <B ref="b3" />
    </A>
    <B id="b1" att="val">
         <C ref="c1" />
    </B>
    <B id="b2">
        someOtherData
    </B>
    <B id="b3">
        moreData
    </B>
    <C id="c1">
         someData
    </C>
</root>
```

Is there a way to achieve this using C# ?

And is there a way to transform the flat xml back to tree structure?  I'd like something as generic as possible, so any xml file could be flattened as such.

There is a [similar question on so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221370/easy-way-to-flatten-xml-file-with-linq), but it doesn't deal with refs.

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for XSLT. BTW we assume your sample XML is not a whole document but an XML fragment, because it has more than one top-level element. In order for the output to be well-formed XML, you have to have a single top-level element. Also, how do you want to handle attributes and text nodes?

Comment: @LarsH good points, I've updated the question

Comment: @sprocket: thanks for the clarifying details. I'm working on an XSLT solution.... should be pretty simple, but I've got some other urgent obligations this morning. If you tag this `xslt` I bet you'll have a solution from somebody else pretty quick. Also, your last closing end-tag `</A>` in your input XML is missing the slash.

Comment: @LarsH Thanks again for your tips, I've made the edits

Comment: @sprocketonline: It happens so that only my solution produces exactly the output you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="Lower" select=
  "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"
  />

 <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select=
  "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"
  />

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*//*" mode="extract">
     <xsl:sort select="count(ancestor::*)" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[ancestor::*[2]]">
   <xsl:variable name="vPos">
     <xsl:number level="any"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:element name="{name()}">
     <xsl:attribute name="ref">
       <xsl:value-of select=
        "concat(translate(name(),$vUpper,$Lower),$vPos)"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="extract">
  <xsl:variable name="vPos">
   <xsl:number level="any"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
       <xsl:value-of select=
        "concat(translate(name(),$vUpper,$Lower),$vPos)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <A>
        <B att="val">
            <C>
                someData
            </C>
        </B>
    </A>
    <A>
        <B>
             someOtherData
        </B>
        <B>
            moreData
        </B>
    </A>
</root>
```

**produces *exactly* the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <A>
      <B ref="b1"/>
   </A>
   <A>
      <B ref="b2"/>
      <B ref="b3"/>
   </A>
   <B id="b1" att="val">
      <C ref="c1"/>
   </B>
   <B id="b2">
             someOtherData
        </B>
   <B id="b3">
            moreData
        </B>
   <C id="c1">
                someData
            </C>
</root>
```

**The reverse transformation is**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kElbyId" match="*" use="@id"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[@ref]">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="deepen"
       select="key('kElbyId',@ref)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[@id]"/>
 <xsl:template match="*[@id]" mode="deepen">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates
        select="@*[not(name()='id')] | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this, reverse transformation is applied on the result of the flattening transformation above, the initial XML document is produced**:

```
<root>
   <A>
      <B att="val">
         <C>
                someData
            </C>
      </B>
   </A>
   <A>
      <B>
             someOtherData
        </B>
      <B>
            moreData
        </B>
   </A>
</root>
```

Answer (score 3):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="vUppercase" select="'QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vLowercase" select="'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:if test="parent::*/parent::*">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(name(),
                                                    $vUppercase,
                                                    $vLowercase)"/>
                    <xsl:number level="any"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="ref"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="ref">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="ref">
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(name(),
                                                $vUppercase,
                                                $vLowercase)"/>
                <xsl:number level="any"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <A>
        <B ref="b1" />
    </A>
    <B att="val" id="b1">
        <C ref="c1" />
    </B>
    <C id="c1">
                    someData
    </C>
    <A>
        <B ref="b2" />
        <B ref="b3" />
    </A>
    <B id="b2">
                 someOtherData
    </B>
    <B id="b3">
                moreData
    </B>
</root>
```

The reverse stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kElementById" match="*[@id]" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:key name="kElementByRef" match="*[@ref]" use="@ref"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[key('kElementByRef',@id)]|
                         *[key('kElementByRef',@id)]/@id"/>
    <xsl:template match="*[@ref]">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('kElementById',@ref)">
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <A>
        <B att="val">
            <C>
                someData
            </C>
        </B>
    </A>
    <A>
        <B>
             someOtherData
        </B>
        <B>
            moreData
        </B>
    </A>
</root>
```

Comment: @Alejandro: Good answer, but in the reverse transformation you are assuming that the only `id` attributes would be generated by the flattening transformation. This, generally, may not be true.

Comment: @Alejandro: Another minor remark is that the question asks for ids starting with lowercase `b`, not with `B`.

Comment: @Dimitre: I was assuming the values of the ids didn't really matter as long as they were unique. But I could be wrong about the OP's requirements.

Comment: @Dimitre: Good catch. Added a lowercase transformation. Strip only refered `@id`: the "flattening" transformation should only preserve original top level element's @id (and we hope they don't crash... ja!)

Comment: @LarsH @Dimitre: We always can think of direffents attribute names for identifiers and references in order to prevent original attributes overwriting.

Comment: @Alejandro: Also the OP wants all `B` elements that are referred to to be grouped together at the end of the document.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off going with @Alejandro's or @Dimitre's stylesheets, but I wanted to post mine since I finished a working version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <!-- copy any non-elements -->
         <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()[not(self::*)]"/>
         <!-- transform descendant elements -->
         <xsl:apply-templates select=".//*" mode="define" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*" mode="define">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/></xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:attribute name="ref"><xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/></xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="ref">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: I did not try to preserve

- the particular id patterns you used. My assumption is that you don't care what the id's are, as long as they're unique and stable. If this assumption is incorrect, the previous two answers show how to generate the IDs according to your pattern.
- the order in which you generated the element definitions, though the order of the original document should be recoverable from my output.
- the fact that your top-level elements don't have id attributes. That would be an easy enough feature to add, as the other answers have done. But hopefully it is not necessary: top-level elements are identifiable as such because there are no references to them.

When running my stylesheet on your sample input, I get this output (the spacing is ugly but I'm not going to fix it since you have other good answers):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>



   <A id="d0e3">

      <B ref="d0e5"/>

   </A>
   <B id="d0e5" att="val">

      <C ref="d0e7"/>

   </B>
   <C id="d0e7">
            someData
         </C>
   <A id="d0e12">

      <B ref="d0e14"/>

      <B ref="d0e17"/>

   </A>
   <B id="d0e14">
         someOtherData
      </B>
   <B id="d0e17">
         moreData
      </B>
</root>
```